# How to do set multiplication(Cartesian product) in R

Tags: r, list, vector, set

I know vectors can represent n-tuples and a list of vectors can represent a set of n-tuples. An easy algorithm would be

```
AxB<-list();k<-1L
for(i in seq_along(A))for(j in seq_along(B)){AxB[[k]]<-c(A[[i]],B[[j]]);k<-k+1L}
```

Are there more elegant data structures and algorithms to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giva a try to `expand.grid` function:

```
a<-list(1,2,6,3)
b<-list("a", "b", "c")
expand.grid(a,b)
```

Your output will be:

```
   Var1 Var2
1     1    a
2     2    a
3     6    a
4     3    a
5     1    b
6     2    b
7     6    b
8     3    b
9     1    c
10    2    c
11    6    c
12    3    c
```

And also look at the `outer` function. But in this case your variables have to be a vector or array.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `CJ` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(a, b)
```

#### data

```
a <- c(1,2,6,3)
b <- c("a", "b", "c")
```